# Regarding the returned vector of dendrogram function

Tags: matlab, dendrogram

I am drawing dendrogram using matlab function like the following

```
[h1,t1,perm1] = dendrogram(z,3);
```

According to MATLAB document, the returned h1 is a vector of handles to the lines in the dendrogram. I do not know that does that mean. For my case, the return h1 is

> h1 =

174.0048

175.0043

How to use this vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, a handle to a graphical object allow you to modify its properties. They are listed in the documentation for each kind of object. You can use the command `set` or the property editor by double-clicking on the line (choose the arrow in the figure toolbar first).

You have this example in the `dendrogram` page to set the width of all lines (but you can also select only a few ones):

```
set(H,'LineWidth',2)
```

See [Line Properties](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/line_props.html) and more generally [Object Properties](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-47570.html).